# locked table by stored procedures in sql

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, sql-server-2005

I have table name called cusdec_boi this table publish as a transaction replication,and client update this table always,problem is some times Lock the table. I Have stored procedure name called ISAutodochrg,this SP runing every 3min.When lock the cusdec_boi table.I found that schedule Sp's taken long time to running.I think problem in following SP's  please tell me  is there any errors found following Sps

```
USE [ISDB]
GO

/****** Object:  StoredProcedure [dbo].[ISAutoDocChrg] Script Date: 5/15/2010 2:12:44 ******/   
SET ANSI_NULLS ON
GO

SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
GO






CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].[ISAutoDocChrg] AS



/* ----------------------------------------CURSER VALRIABLE>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>  */
DECLARE @ConsigneeTIN varchar(17),
@InstanceId  nchar(10),
@PPC varchar(17),
@OfficeCd  varchar(5),
@NoticeDate datetime,
@IDE_TYP_TYP char(1),
@DeclarantTIN varchar(11),

@Sad_Reg_serial varchar(1),

/* ---------------------------------------CURSER VALRIABLES<<<<<<<<<<<<<<  */

/*--------------------------------------SVAT Variables >>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>> */
@SVATAmount money,
@VATAmount money,
@NSVATAmount money,
@SVATStatus varchar,
@Balance money,
-- Version 1.2 >>
@InvestorTIN varchar(11),
@InvTIN varchar(11),
@InvestorPPC varchar(17),
@PPC_ChkCount smallint,
@TypeofCompany varchar(1),
@PPCCount int,

@DecOnAccCount int,
@InvOnAccCount int,


@OnAcc_DecCount smallint,
@OnAcc_ConsiCount smallint,
-- Version 1.2 <<

/*-------------------------------------Create References>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>*/
@TheCount1 int,
@TheCount2 varchar(4),
@RefNo varchar(11) ,
@CostCentercd varchar(3),
@Doc_ChgCont smallint,
@NoteType char(2),




@DOCSVATAmount money,
@DOCVATAmount money,
@DOCNSVATAmount money,

@GRNSVATAmount money,
@GRNVATAmount money,
@GRNNSVATAmount money,
@ChrgCatCd  Varchar(10)


SELECT    @DOCSVATAmount= RATE,@DOCNSVATAmount=TOTAL,@DOCVATAmount=TAX
FROM         dbo.ISChrgCatRate
where Version='0' and ChrgCatCd='010104'

SELECT    @GRNSVATAmount= RATE,@GRNNSVATAmount=TOTAL,@GRNVATAmount=TAX
FROM         dbo.ISChrgCatRate
where Version='0' and ChrgCatCd='010105'



/*--------------------------------------SVAT Variables <<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<< */

/*--------------------------------------Create Csr>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>*/
DECLARE @getgetCusDec_BOI CURSOR
SET @getgetCusDec_BOI= CURSOR 
    FOR
SELECT ConsigneeTIN, InstanceId,PPC,OfficeCd,Doc_Chg_Date,Doc_ChgCont,IDE_TYP_TYP,DeclarantTIN,PPC_ChkCount,InvTIN,OnAcc_DecCount,OnAcc_ConsiCount,Sad_Reg_serial
FROM CusDec_BOI where Doc_Chg_Flag='0'
/*--------------------------------------Create Csr<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<*/

OPEN @getgetCusDec_BOI



FETCH NEXT
FROM @getgetCusDec_BOI INTO @ConsigneeTIN,@InstanceId,@PPC,@OfficeCd,@NoticeDate,@Doc_ChgCont,@IDE_TYP_TYP,@DeclarantTIN,@PPC_ChkCount,@InvTIN,@OnAcc_DecCount,@OnAcc_ConsiCount,@Sad_Reg_serial
WHILE @@FETCH_STATUS = 0
BEGIN

set @Balance=0
set @SVATStatus=null

IF (@Sad_Reg_serial='G'or @Sad_Reg_serial='Y') 
BEGIN
    SET @SVATAmount =@GRNSVATAmount
    SET @VATAmount=@GRNVATAmount
    SET @NSVATAmount=@GRNNSVATAmount
    SET @ChrgCatCd = '010105'
END

ELSE
BEGIN 
    SET @SVATAmount=@DOCSVATAmount
    SET @VATAmount=@DOCVATAmount
    SET @NSVATAmount=@DOCNSVATAmount
    SET @ChrgCatCd = '010104'
END

SET @InvestorTIN=NULL
SET @InvestorPPC=NULL
SET @PPCCount=0


PRINT @InstanceId + 'COSDEC in Service'

SET @NoteType=NULL

if (substring(@PPC,15,2)='00')
    BEGIN --(A)
    PRINT 'BOI PPC'
    SELECT @InvestorTIN=TIN,@InvestorPPC=WareHouseCd
    FROM ISWareHouse
    --where InvPPC=@PPC
    where WareHouseCd=@PPC

    SELECT @PPCCount=COUNT(WareHouseCd)
    FROM ISWareHouse
    --FROM ISInvSubContractLnk
    --where InvPPC=@PPC 
    where WareHouseCd=@PPC  




    SET @NoteType='09'
    --Notification  /@PPC_ChkCount
    END --(A)
ELSE -- IF (substring(@PPC,8,1)='S')
    BEGIN --(B)
    PRINT 'SUB PPC'
    SELECT @InvestorTIN=TIN,@InvestorPPC=WareHouseCd
    FROM ISWareHouse
    where WareHouseCd=substring(@PPC,1,14) + '00'



    SELECT @PPCCount=COUNT(WareHouseCd)
    FROM ISWareHouse
    where WareHouseCd=@PPC



    SET @NoteType='10'
    --Notification /@PPC_ChkCount
    END --(B)

--if(@InvestorTIN=NULL AND @InvestorPPC=NULL AND @PPC_ChkCount=0)
    if(@PPCCount=0 AND @PPC_ChkCount=0)

    --PRINT  ' <Investor NOT Identified... [PPCCODE/ LINK TABLE]'

-- TOP 7 IF
    BEGIN--(C)
    PRINT  '<Investor NOT Identified[WareHouse Table]'
                EXEC CreateIndexCommon
                @IndexType = 'ON',
                @Ref= @RefNo OUTPUT
                BEGIN TRAN T7

                Update CUSDEC_BOI Set PPC_ChkDate=getdate(),PPC_ChkCount=1 where InstanceId=@InstanceId
                --Insert into ISOnlineNotification( TIN_SubTIN, ONRefNo, NotificationTypeCd, ReferenceNo, UserEntered)
                --  Values(@ConsigneeTIN,@RefNo,'01',@InstanceId,'SYS')
                -- Version 1.2
                -- Insert into ISOnlineNotification( TIN_SubTIN, ONRefNo, NotificationTypeCd, ReferenceNo, UserEntered)
                Insert into ISOnlineNotification( TIN_SubTIN, ONRefNo, NotificationTypeCd, ReferenceNo, UserEntered)
                    Values(@DeclarantTIN,@RefNo,@NoteType,@InstanceId,'SYS')

                IF @@error <> 0
                ROLLBACK TRAN T7
                COMMIT TRAN T7

    END --(C)



--ELSE if(@InvestorTIN<>NULL AND @InvestorPPC<>NULL)
ELSE IF(@PPCCount>0)
-->> TOP 7 ELSE BEGIN
BEGIN --(D)
PRINT  'Investor Identified> ' + @InvestorTIN + '[TIN]>  ' + @InvestorPPC + '[PPC]> ' 


    --if (@InvTIN is Null and @InvestorTIN is not null)
    if (@InvestorTIN is not null)
    BEGIN
     Update CusDec_BOI set InvTIN=@InvestorTIN where InstanceId=@InstanceId
    END
-- Took it below @@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@ >>
set @DecOnAccCount=0
SELECT @DecOnAccCount = COUNT(TIN_SubTIN)
FROM ISOnAcctRegistry
where TIN_SubTIN=@DeclarantTIN and Status='1'

if (@DecOnAccCount>0)
    BEGIN
    SELECT @Balance= Balance
    FROM ISOnAcctRegistry
    where TIN_SubTIN=@DeclarantTIN and Status='1'
    PRINT 'DECLARANT FOUND IN OnAccount> ' + @DeclarantTIN + ' BALANCE> '  +convert(varchar,@Balance)
END 
ELSE IF (@DecOnAccCount=0 AND @OnAcc_DecCount=0 )
    BEGIN
    PRINT 'DECLARANT NOT FOUND IN OnAccount [Cannot Proceed]> ' + @DeclarantTIN
    set @NoteType='11'
            EXEC CreateIndexCommon
            @IndexType = 'ON',
            @Ref= @RefNo OUTPUT

            BEGIN TRAN T8
            Update CUSDEC_BOI Set OnAcc_DecDate=getdate(),OnAcc_DecCount=1 where InstanceId=@InstanceId

            Insert into ISOnlineNotification( TIN_SubTIN, ONRefNo, NotificationTypeCd, ReferenceNo, UserEntered)
                Values(@DeclarantTIN,@RefNo,@NoteType,@InstanceId,'SYS')

            IF @@error <> 0
            ROLLBACK TRAN T8
            COMMIT TRAN T8  


    END
-- Took it below @@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@ <<
SET @InvOnAccCount=0
SELECT @InvOnAccCount=COUNT(TIN_SubTIN)
FROM ISOnAcctRegistry
where TIN_SubTIN=LEFT(@InvestorTIN,9) and Status='1'

IF (@InvOnAccCount>0 AND @DecOnAccCount>0)
BEGIN
    SELECT @SVATStatus=SVATStatus
    FROM ISOnAcctRegistry
    where TIN_SubTIN=left(@InvestorTIN,9) and Status='1' 
    PRINT 'INVESTOR FOUND IN OnAccount> ' + LEFT(@InvestorTIN,9) + ' ' + 'SVAT STATUS> ' + @SVATStatus  
END
ELSE IF (@InvOnAccCount=0 AND @OnAcc_ConsiCount=0 AND @DecOnAccCount>0)
    BEGIN
    PRINT 'INVESTOR NOT FOUND IN OnAccount for SVAT STATUS [Cannot Proceed]> ' + LEFT(@InvestorTIN,9)
            set @NoteType='12'
            EXEC CreateIndexCommon
            @IndexType = 'ON',
            @Ref= @RefNo OUTPUT

            BEGIN TRAN T9
            Update CUSDEC_BOI Set OnAcc_ConsiDate=getdate(),OnAcc_ConsiCount=1 where InstanceId=@InstanceId         
            Insert into ISOnlineNotification( TIN_SubTIN, ONRefNo, NotificationTypeCd, ReferenceNo, UserEntered)
                Values(@DeclarantTIN,@RefNo,@NoteType,@InstanceId,'SYS')

            IF @@error <> 0
            ROLLBACK TRAN T9
            COMMIT TRAN T9  
END


--PRINT 'DECLARANT>' + @DeclarantTIN + '  ' + @SVATStatus + 'Declarant Identified'


 -- Version 1.2
 --ISChargeSummary Insert @InvestorPPC and @DeclarantTIN
 --ISOnlineNotification @DeclarantTIN Notifications will be sent to him
  set @CostCentercd=null
  set @NoteType=null
  Select @CostCentercd=CostCenterCd From ISOfficeCode where OfficeCd=@OfficeCd

  set @RefNo=null
  ------------------------------------PPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPP    PPPP> (1.0)
if (@SVATStatus='1' OR @SVATStatus='2')
BEGIN   
    --Create Receipt Reference----------------------------------------------------------- (1.1)<
    if (@Balance>=@SVATAmount)
        BEGIN
            EXEC CreateIndexCommon
            @IndexType = 'CH',
            @Ref= @RefNo OUTPUT


            -- TRANS (1) >>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>
            BEGIN TRAN T1   

            if (@SVATStatus='1')
                BEGIN
                insert into ISChrgDetail (CHRefNo, ChrgCatCd, Qty, Amount, Tax,NetAmount)
                    values(@RefNo,@ChrgCatCd,'1',@SVATAmount,@VATAmount,@SVATAmount)
                insert into ISChrgSummary (CHRefNo, TIN_SubTIN, PPC, TotAmount, TotTax, 
                    NetAmount, UserEntered, DateEntered, CostCenterCd, SVATStatus,ReferenceNo)
                    -- Version 1.2
                    --values(@RefNo,@ConsigneeTIN,@PPC,@NSVATAmount,@VATAmount,@SVATAmount,'SYS',getdate(),@CostCentercd ,'1',@InstanceId)
                    --values(@RefNo,@DeclarantTIN,@InvestorPPC,@NSVATAmount,@VATAmount,@SVATAmount,'SYS',getdate(),@CostCentercd ,'1',@InstanceId)
                    values(@RefNo,@DeclarantTIN,@InvestorPPC,@SVATAmount,@VATAmount,@SVATAmount,'SYS',getdate(),@CostCentercd ,'1',@InstanceId)

                END

            if (@SVATStatus='2')
                BEGIN
                insert into ISChrgDetail (CHRefNo, ChrgCatCd, Qty, Amount, Tax,NetAmount)
                    values(@RefNo,@ChrgCatCd,'1',@SVATAmount,'',@SVATAmount)
                insert into ISChrgSummary (CHRefNo, TIN_SubTIN, PPC, TotAmount, TotTax, 
                    NetAmount, UserEntered, DateEntered, CostCenterCd, SVATStatus,ReferenceNo)
                    -- Version 1.2
                    --values(@RefNo,@ConsigneeTIN,@PPC,@NSVATAmount,@VATAmount,@SVATAmount,'SYS',getdate(),@CostCentercd ,'1',@InstanceId)
                --values(@RefNo,@DeclarantTIN,@InvestorPPC,@NSVATAmount,'',@SVATAmount,'SYS',getdate(),@CostCentercd ,'2',@InstanceId)
                values(@RefNo,@DeclarantTIN,@InvestorPPC,@SVATAmount,'',@SVATAmount,'SYS',getdate(),@CostCentercd ,'2',@InstanceId)

                END


            Update CUSDEC_BOI set Doc_Chg_Flag='1', Doc_Chg_Date=getdate()  where InstanceId=@InstanceId


            IF @@error <> 0
            ROLLBACK TRAN T1
            COMMIT TRAN T
        END

    -- Put First Notification if [@NoticeDate=NULL]
    --else if (@Balance<@SVATAmount  and  (@NoticeDate=NULL or @NoticeDate<>convert(varchar(10),getdate(),101)) )
    else if (@Balance<@SVATAmount  and  (@NoticeDate is NULL))      
        BEGIN


        IF (@IDE_TYP_TYP='1')
            BEGIN
            SET @NoteType='01'
            END
        ELSE IF (@IDE_TYP_TYP='0')
            BEGIN
            SET @NoteType='03'
            END 


            --Create Notification Reference----------------------------------------------------------- (1.1.2)>
            EXEC CreateIndexCommon
            @IndexType = 'ON',
            @Ref= @RefNo OUTPUT
            --Insert into TESTT (Ref) values(@RefNo)
            --Create Reference----------------------------------------------------------------------------- (1.1.2)<

            -- TRANS (2) >>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>
            BEGIN TRAN T2

            Update CUSDEC_BOI Set Doc_Chg_Date=getdate(),Doc_ChgCont=1 where InstanceId=@InstanceId
            --Insert into ISOnlineNotification( TIN_SubTIN, ONRefNo, NotificationTypeCd, ReferenceNo, UserEntered)
            --  Values(@ConsigneeTIN,@RefNo,'01',@InstanceId,'SYS')
            -- Version 1.2
            -- Insert into ISOnlineNotification( TIN_SubTIN, ONRefNo, NotificationTypeCd, ReferenceNo, UserEntered)
            Insert into ISOnlineNotification( TIN_SubTIN, ONRefNo, NotificationTypeCd, ReferenceNo, UserEntered)
                Values(@DeclarantTIN,@RefNo,@NoteType,@InstanceId,'SYS')

            IF @@error <> 0
            ROLLBACK TRAN T2
            COMMIT TRAN T2

        END


    --Put Second Reminders if First one is already sent >> convert(varchar(10),@NoticeDate,101) <>convert(varchar(10),getdate(),101)) 


    else if (@Balance<@SVATAmount  and  (convert(varchar(10),@NoticeDate,101) <>convert(varchar(10),getdate(),101)) AND @Doc_ChgCont<10 )
        BEGIN

        IF (@IDE_TYP_TYP='1')
            BEGIN
            SET @NoteType='02'
            END
        ELSE IF (@IDE_TYP_TYP='0')
            BEGIN
            SET @NoteType='04'
            END 



        --Create Notification Reference----------------------------------------------------------- (1.1.2)>
        EXEC CreateIndexCommon
        @IndexType = 'ON',
        @Ref= @RefNo OUTPUT
        --Create Reference----------------------------------------------------------------------------- (1.1.2)<


        -- TRANS (3)  >>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>
        BEGIN TRAN T3
        Update CUSDEC_BOI Set Doc_Chg_Date=getdate(),Doc_ChgCont=Doc_ChgCont+1 where InstanceId=@InstanceId
        --Insert into ISOnlineNotification( TIN_SubTIN, ONRefNo, NotificationTypeCd, ReferenceNo, UserEntered)
        --  Values(@ConsigneeTIN,@RefNo,'02',@InstanceId,'SYS')
        Insert into ISOnlineNotification( TIN_SubTIN, ONRefNo, NotificationTypeCd, ReferenceNo, UserEntered)
            -- Version 1.2
            --Values(@ConsigneeTIN,@RefNo,@NoteType,@InstanceId,'SYS')
            Values(@DeclarantTIN,@RefNo,@NoteType,@InstanceId,'SYS')

        IF @@error <> 0
        ROLLBACK TRAN T3
        COMMIT TRAN T3
    END
END


------------------------------------------------------PPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPP> (2.0)
else if (@SVATStatus='0')
BEGIN

if (@Balance>=@NSVATAmount)
    BEGIN
    --Create Receipt Reference------------------------------------------------------------------ (2.1.1)>   
    EXEC CreateIndexCommon
             @IndexType = 'CH',
             @Ref= @RefNo OUTPUT
    --Create Notification Reference----------------------------------------------------------- (2.1.1)<

    -- TRANS (4) >>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>
    BEGIN TRAN T4

    insert into ISChrgDetail (CHRefNo, ChrgCatCd, Qty, Amount, Tax,NetAmount)
        values(@RefNo,@ChrgCatCd,'1',@SVATAmount,@VATAmount,@NSVATAmount)

    insert into ISChrgSummary (CHRefNo, TIN_SubTIN, PPC, TotAmount, TotTax, 
        NetAmount, UserEntered, DateEntered, CostCenterCd, SVATStatus,ReferenceNo)
        --Version 1.2
        --values(@RefNo,@ConsigneeTIN,@PPC,@NSVATAmount,@VATAmount,@NSVATAmount,'SYS',getdate(),@CostCentercd ,'0',@InstanceId)
        --values(@RefNo,@DeclarantTIN,@InvestorPPC,@NSVATAmount,@VATAmount,@NSVATAmount,'SYS',getdate(),@CostCentercd ,'0',@InstanceId)
        values(@RefNo,@DeclarantTIN,@InvestorPPC,@SVATAmount,@VATAmount,@NSVATAmount,'SYS',getdate(),@CostCentercd ,'0',@InstanceId)

    Update CUSDEC_BOI set Doc_Chg_Flag='1', Doc_Chg_Date=getdate()  where InstanceId=@InstanceId

    IF @@error <> 0
    ROLLBACK TRAN T4
    COMMIT TRAN T4
    END
--END

--else
-- Put First Reminder/ Reminder type code is (1) >>>>>>  (@NoticeDate=NULL) )
--else if (@Balance<@SVATAmount  and  (@NoticeDate=NULL or @NoticeDate<>convert(varchar(10),getdate(),101)) )
else if (@Balance<@NSVATAmount  and  (@NoticeDate is NULL) )
BEGIN
        IF (@IDE_TYP_TYP='1')
            BEGIN
            SET @NoteType='01'
            END
        ELSE IF (@IDE_TYP_TYP='0')
            BEGIN
            SET @NoteType='03'
            END 


    --Create Notification Reference----------------------------------------------------------- (2.2.1)>
    EXEC CreateIndexCommon
        @IndexType = 'ON',
        @Ref= @RefNo OUTPUT
        --Insert into TESTT (Ref) values(@RefNo)
    --Create Notification Reference----------------------------------------------------------- (2.2.1)<
        /*Insert into ISOnlineNotification( TIN_SubTIN, ONRefNo, NotificationTypeCd, Remarks, UserEntered)
            Values(@ConsigneeTIN,@RefNo,'1012',@InstanceId,'SYS') */

    -- TRANS (5) >>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>



    BEGIN TRAN T5

        --Insert into ISOnlineNotification( TIN_SubTIN, ONRefNo, NotificationTypeCd, ReferenceNo, UserEntered)
        --  Values(@ConsigneeTIN,@RefNo,'01',@InstanceId,'SYS')

        Insert into ISOnlineNotification( TIN_SubTIN, ONRefNo, NotificationTypeCd, ReferenceNo, UserEntered)
            -- Version 1.2
            --Values(@ConsigneeTIN,@RefNo,@NoteType,@InstanceId,'SYS')
            Values(@DeclarantTIN,@RefNo,@NoteType,@InstanceId,'SYS')            

        Update CUSDEC_BOI Set Doc_Chg_Date=getdate(),Doc_ChgCont=1 where InstanceId=@InstanceId

    IF @@error <> 0
    ROLLBACK TRAN T5
    COMMIT TRAN T5
    END
----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------<

-- Send Second Reminders/ Reminder type code is (3) >>>>> (convert(varchar(10),@NoticeDate,101) <>convert(varchar(10),getdate(),101))
else if (@Balance<@NSVATAmount  and  (convert(varchar(10),@NoticeDate,101) <>convert(varchar(10),getdate(),101))AND @Doc_ChgCont<10 )
    BEGIN
        IF (@IDE_TYP_TYP='1')
            BEGIN
            SET @NoteType='02'
            END
        ELSE IF (@IDE_TYP_TYP='0')
            BEGIN
            SET @NoteType='04'
            END 



    --Create Notification Reference----------------------------------------------------------- (2.2.1)>
    EXEC CreateIndexCommon
        @IndexType = 'ON',
        @Ref= @RefNo OUTPUT
        --Insert into TESTT (Ref) values(@RefNo)
    --Create Notification Reference----------------------------------------------------------- (2.2.1)<

        /*Insert into ISOnlineNotification( TIN_SubTIN, ONRefNo, NotificationTypeCd, Remarks, UserEntered)
        Values(@ConsigneeTIN,@RefNo,'1012',@InstanceId,'SYS') */

        -- TRANS (6) >>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>

        BEGIN TRAN T6
        --Insert into ISOnlineNotification( TIN_SubTIN, ONRefNo, NotificationTypeCd, ReferenceNo, UserEntered)
        --  Values(@ConsigneeTIN,@RefNo,'02',@InstanceId,'SYS')
          Insert into ISOnlineNotification( TIN_SubTIN, ONRefNo, NotificationTypeCd, ReferenceNo, UserEntered)
            -- Version 1.2
            --Values(@ConsigneeTIN,@RefNo,@NoteType,@InstanceId,'SYS')
            Values(@DeclarantTIN,@RefNo,@NoteType,@InstanceId,'SYS')
        Update CUSDEC_BOI Set Doc_Chg_Date=getdate(),Doc_ChgCont=Doc_ChgCont+1 where InstanceId=@InstanceId

        IF @@error <> 0
        ROLLBACK TRAN T6
        COMMIT TRAN T6
    END
 END
----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------<

--<< TOP 7 ELSE END

END --(D)


set @ConsigneeTIN=null
set @InstanceId=null
set @PPC=null
set @OfficeCd=null
set @NoticeDate=null
set @DeclarantTIN=null
set @PPC_ChkCount=0
set @InvTIN=Null

set @OnAcc_DecCount=Null
set @OnAcc_ConsiCount=Null
set @Sad_Reg_serial=null

FETCH NEXT
FROM @getgetCusDec_BOI INTO     @ConsigneeTIN,@InstanceId,@PPC,@OfficeCd,@NoticeDate,@Doc_ChgCont,@IDE_TYP_TYP,@DeclarantTIN,@PPC_ChkCount,@InvTIN,
@OnAcc_DecCount,@OnAcc_ConsiCount,@Sad_Reg_serial
END
/*---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------*/

CLOSE @getgetCusDec_BOI
DEALLOCATE @getgetCusDec_BOI






GO
```

Comment: Why do you think re-posting **exactly** the same question will change anything if the first one was already closed?

Answer (score 0):

Mate, as a starting point, could try using **sp_who2** to find out if the long running times are a result of blocking sessions.